# Send List in Service Angular 4

Tags: angular

I create an array of objects in my service

```
public producto(oportunidad?: Oportunidad, productoAntiguo?: ProductoOportunidad, productoNuevo?: ProductoOportunidad, ) {
    let registros = new Array;
    //OBJETO NUEVO
    if (productoAntiguo == null) {
        registros.push(this.initRegistroProducto("OPORTUNIDAD_PRODUCTO_SAVE", "OPORTUNIDAD", oportunidad, "nombreProducto", "", productoNuevo.producto.id));
        registros.push(this.initRegistroProducto("OPORTUNIDAD_PRODUCTO_SAVE", "OPORTUNIDAD", oportunidad, "codigoProducto", "", productoNuevo.codigoProducto));
    }
    console.debug(registros);
    this.createList(registros);
}
```

And once I have the array I want to send it back at once

```
 createList(registros: any): Observable<Registro> {
    let registrosConvert = new Array;
    registros.forEach(registro => {
        let registroConvert = this.convert(registro);
        registrosConvert.push(registroConvert);
    });

    return this.http.post(this.resourceUrl + "/list", registrosConvert).map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json();
    });
}
```

It does not even make the call back, I'm new to Angular 4, there's something wrong with syntax.

I send the list and you should not return anything, they are one records to save in the BBDD and nothing else.

Someone can help me.

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have any errors displayed in your browser ?

Comment: Not even the call, in the "Network" tab of "Chrome" nothing comes out.

Comment: It's pretty hard to know where the issue is coming from... Could you provide a minimalist plunkr example ?

Comment: subscribe <- I needed to add